# How to add Conditional blocks for image content in mailchimp ?

Tags: automation, html-email, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to put conditional merge tags to image cards/blocks in mailchimp. But i am not able to find any options there.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by wrapping an image block with two text blocks.

In the one before the image block put the IF statement (e.g. *|IF:MC_LANGUAGE=sl|*) and in the the one after the image put END IF statement (*|END:IF|*)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to conditionally put the recipient's first and last name at the top of my HTML email:

*|IF:FNAME|*Information for *|FNAME|**|END:IF|* *|IF:LNAME|**|LNAME|**|END:IF|*

Comment: Suppose i have one image block instead of text editor. 
How can i add conditional to that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "image block" since you referenced the merge tags of MailChimp. If you are trying to include or exclude an image in your email, you'll need to use the conditional capabilities of HTML such as <!--[if condition]> html coding <![endif]--> or media queries.